# File upload using attachement_fu in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, file-upload, attachment-fu

I want to know how to upload files(other than images) using attachement_fu plugin in rails. I successfully uploaded images using attachement_fu, but wasn't able to upload other kinds of files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a code example of how you configure your model to accept the attachment?

Basically, to upload types other then images, you need to either omit the `:content_type` option, or give the correct content type.

So instead of (for example):

```
has_attachment :content_type => :image, :max_size => 5.megabytes
```

You need to provide something like:

```
has_attachment :content_type => 'application/pdf', :max_size => 5.megabytes
```

or just `has_attachment` without `:content_type` (this will accept all types).

Take a look at the [attachemnt_fu README](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu) for more examples.